# How can I run a script whenever the device is not connected to a wifi network?

Tags: wifi, networkmanager

I would like my Raspberry Pi Zero W to create a captive portal that lets me use my smartphone to connect it to a new wifi network whenever it is disconnected from the internet. I recently came across [`wifi-connect`](https://github.com/balena-os/wifi-connect), which does the captive portal part quite nicely.

Now, how do I run the `wifi-connect` command whenever the raspberry pi is disconnected from a network? Or more generally, how do I run a simple script whenever a device is disconnected from wifi networks?

I would like it to run in the following cases:

- No network found after booting up
- Becomes disconnected from a network (eg. the router turned off or the device moved out of range)

But I would also like `wifi-connect` to stop if a "known" network is found (eg. the router turned back on or the device moved back in range).

Should I create a script in `/etc/network/if-down.d` or `/etc/network/if-post-down.d`? Or, since `wifi-connect` uses `NetworkManager`, should I put this script in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d`? Or do I create a service that `systemd` runs?

Comment: this may help ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=debian+how+to+detect+when+wifi+network+is+lost&ia=web

Comment: I've not used `wifi-connect`, but if its installation on your system has created a new network manager, then I'd suggest you operate with that NM; i.e. ask the folks at Balena-OS. By default, RPi uses `dhcpcd` as its network manager, and it's unclear to me if your question is "on topic" here. Surely they've not created a `NetworkManager` with no user interface??

Comment: I don't quite understand: what's the point in running a captive portal when the Pi has no Internet connection? You want to make your users enter the credentials only to tell them there's no Internet after all?

Answer (score 0):

For sure it is interested to have this. Suppose the wifi password on the router is changed, you need to be able to re-enter it.

I have created for this a script. The script is started with systemctl.
It starts at boot wait 20 seconds to allow all to come up and see if there is wifi, if no wifi, the portal appears. If wifi goes down during a normal connection (pasword change eg), the portal appears for 5 minutes and than, depending on entering a valid wifi/pwd, or go back to wifi as entered, or will kill the portal and check if there is again wifi after 5 minutes.
After this sequence, wait 5 minutes and check the whole thing again.
works for me on a pi4B.
Most likely not the best solution, I'm not a unix thing specialist, but it works.
Put the script in /etc/wifi-connect/start.sh
Make it run:

```
Ø cp wifi-connect.service /etc/systemd/system/wifi-connect.service
Ø chmod 0664 wifi-connect.service (not executable, not world-writable)
Ø sudo systemctl daemon-reload
Ø sudo systemctl enable wifi-connect.service
Ø sudo systemctl start wifi-connect.service
```

script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Voor startup purposes
sleep 20


while true;do

# Choose a condition for running WiFi Connect according to your use case:

# 1. Is there a default gateway?
# ip route | grep default
# 2. Is there Internet connectivity?
# nmcli -t g | grep full
# 3. Is there Internet connectivity via a google ping?

wget --spider http://google.com 2>&1

# 4. Is there an active WiFi connection?
#iwgetid -r
# dit werkt niet goed!!

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    printf 'Skipping WiFi Connect\n'
else
    printf 'Starting WiFi Connect\n'
# Kill eventueel overblijvende instances    
    sudo nmcli connection delete id EMServer && sleep 5    
# Setup captive portal voor 5 minuten, daarna terug wifi proberen voor 50 seconden
    sudo wifi-connect  --activity-timeout 300 --portal-ssid EMServer
fi
sleep 350
done
```

Comment: how does this answer the question? ... please clarify it,  or delete it